# Expected frequencies

Tags: r, probability, poisson-distribution

Using the Poisson distribution I have been able to calculate the probability for frequencies from 0:7 but now have no idea how to compute the expected frequency for those values or compare the observed values.

```
dpois(x=0:7,lambda=2.009)
```

```
probabilities based on the above code
[1] 0.134122730 0.269452565 0.270665102 0.181255397 0.091035523 0.036578073 0.012247558
[8] 0.003515049
```

```
table of actual observations used to calculate mean
  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7 
136 272 262 178  94  46  11   1
```

I know the first step would be turning the probabilities into expected values but I am a bit lost about the best way to do that.

Comment: You seem to be preparing to do a chi-squared test. But you don't say what null hypothesis you are testing. Are you testing that the observations are consistent with **some** Poisson distribution? Or whether the observations are consistent with a **particular** Poisson distribution with a given $\lambda ?$ [Where did you get $\lambda=2.009 ?]$ The degrees of freedom in the chi-squared test depend on the answers to these questions.

Comment: I got the 2.009 from the average of the total observations (seen in the table) noted during the 1000 mins time period they were recorded.

Comment: I don't think I am meant to go down the full hypothesis testing route but I'm not fully sure. All I am told is 'Compute the expected frequencies for each value in the frequency distribution' then 'Compare the expected frequencies to those actually observed values from the dataset and comment on your findings'. No additional information will be given beyond those instructions

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the expected counts should be based on the
probabilities $p_k$ in the distribution $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda=2.009),$
where category `7` is interpreted as `7 or more` so that the
probabilities add to unity. Then expected counts are $E_k = 1000p_k.$

```
p.0 = dpois(0:7, 2.009)
p = p.0;  p[8] = 1 - ppois(6,2.009);  p
[1] 0.134122730 0.269452565 0.270665102 0.181255397
[5] 0.091035523 0.036578073 0.012247558 0.004643052
E = p*1000; E
[1] 134.122730 269.452565 270.665102 181.255397
[5]  91.035523  36.578073  12.247558   4.643052
```

The observed counts are `x` from your table:

```
x
[1] 136 272 262 178  94  46  11   1
```

You could "compare" them by eye and say observed and expected counts "look pretty much the same."

Or you could compute the chi-squared 'goodness-of-fit' statistic
$Q = \sum_{k=1}^8 \frac{(x_k-E_k)^2}{E_k} = 5.895,$ which is small for
'good' fits of observed counts to expected counts.

```
Q = sum((x-E)^2/E); Q
[1] 5.895211
```

In optimal circumstances $Q \stackrel{aprx}{\sim}\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=8-2=6),$
which has 95th quantile $c=12.592,$ called the critical value. Because
$Q < c,$ one says the the null hypothesis that the counts come from some
Poisson distribution is not rejected. So data are consistent with a Poisson model at the '5% level of significance'.

```
qchisq(.95,6)
[1] 12.59159
```

If $\lambda$ had been given, so you were testing the data against the particular
model $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda=2.009)$ then the degrees of freedom of $Q$ would
be $\nu = 8-1 = 7.$ However, the degrees of freedom are reduced to $\nu = 6$ because you used the data to estimate $\lambda.$

Roughly speakng, the 'optimal circumstances' mentioned above are that all expected counts are greater then $5,$ as is (almost) true for your data.